# DMS Migration Task Creation Error using S3 as source and Migration Type as full-load-and-cdc

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-dms, aws-cdk-typescript

I am using AMS CDK (v2) to create DMS task (v3.4.6) and endpoints.
For the DMS task, migration type is `full-load-and-cdc`. Source endpoint is S3 and target endpoint is DynamoDB.
For the S3 source endpoint, specified parameters in S3Settings as :

```
bucketName: props.bucketName,
cdcPath: 'changedData',
csvDelimiter: ',',
csvRowDelimiter: '\\n',
externalTableDefinition: JSON.stringify({....})
```

CodePipeline fails with the CloudFormation error:

```
Parameter cdcPath is required when task is configured for ongoing replication with Amazon S3 as a source. (Service: AWSDatabaseMigrationService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException
```

Where to specify cdcPath parameter for DMS migration task?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you configuring any ExtraConnectionAttributes?

Comment: No @Ross Bush, where do I need to configure it?

Comment: There is a section "Endpoint settings when using Amazon S3 as a target for AWS" in the link below. You will find an Endpoint setting for cdcPath there too. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html You may have luck setting one, the other, or both.

Comment: In my case, S3 is a source and not the target. Will try it out anyhow

Answer (score 0):

I am certain that you can set the extra connection attributes for a Source S3 bucket via the cli. The image below works without a problem. Maybe you are missing the cdc-path on the endpoint when source/target is S3.

[image]